# Probability to win

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

The fine print on an instant lottery ticket claims that one in nine tickets win a prize.  What is the probability that you win at least twice if you purchase ten tickets?

Answer (score 2):

The value you have, $\frac{1}{9}$, is a probability of success, $p$. Denote the full set of outcomes $\Omega$. The set of outcomes you are interested in is $\Omega_s$. Now try to find $P(\Omega) - P(\Omega_s^c)$ where $\Omega_s^c$ is the set of outcomes complimentary to the one you are interested in using Binomial distribution.

Answer (score 2):

The probability that you win at least twice is equal to one minus the probability that you win 0 or 1 time.  In notation: $$P(\text{win at least } 2) = 1 - P(\text{win } 1 \text{ or } 0)$$

The probability that you win $0$ times is $$P(0) = \binom{10}{0}\left(\frac{1}{9}\right)^{10}$$

Now all that's left to do is find the probability that you win $1$ time.  Can you take it from here?

Comment: Is still don't get it. Please help ke more.

Comment: You can either add the probabilities of winning $2, 3, 4, \dots, 10$ or just take the total($1$) minus the probabilities of winning $0$ or $1$, which is what I have done here.